# How to return several list without the model in Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I returns serval list in Rest Framework?

I have serializers.py

```
class HostTypeSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HostType
        fields = "__all__"
class DiskOSTypeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DiskOSType
        fields = "__all__"
class DiskEssenceTypeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DiskEssenceType
        fields = "__all__"
```

I have the three Serializers, and I want to return data like bellow:

```
{
    hosttypes:[the HostTypeSerializer's list data ],
    diskostype:[the DiskOSTypeSerializer's list data],
    diskessencetype:[the DiskEssenceTypeSerializer's list data], 
}
```

I tried but failed, but I don't know how to do with that:

```
class DiskPreCreateSerialzer(ModelSerializer):
    hosttypes = HostTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    diskostypes = DiskOSTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    diskessencetypes = DiskEssenceTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:

        fields = (
            "hosttypes",
            "diskostypes",
            "diskessencetypes",
        )
```

In views.py:

```
class DiskPreCreateAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = DiskPreCreateSerialzer
    permission_classes = []
    ...
```

I want to use this Serializer to returns my requirement, but failed, how can I get that?

---

**EDIT**

I don't know how to write my `DiskPreCreateAPIView` now, because I don't know how to get the data to return.

```
class DiskPreCreateAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = DiskPreCreateSerialzer
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):

        return Response(data=xxx, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please mention the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use base `Serializer` instead of `ModelSerializer`:

```
class DiskPreCreateSerialzer(Serializer):
    hosttypes = HostTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    diskostypes = DiskOSTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    diskessencetypes = DiskEssenceTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

And in your view pass dict with your lists to this serializer:

```
class DiskPreCreateAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = DiskPreCreateSerialzer
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):
        ...
        serializer = self.serializer_class({
            'hosttypes': hosttypes_qs,
            'diskostype':diskostype_qs,
            'diskessencetype': diskessencetype_qs,
        })
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: and How to do with the view?

Comment: Please, attach your view

Comment: Its in my post `DiskPreCreateAPIView `.

Comment: Please, attach your full view

Comment: see my edit, I don't know how to get the return data(means the several list) now.